# Ruby ri tool will not work.

Tags: ruby, macos

I am trying to make use of the ri tools and cannot get them to work. I have tried `rvm docs generate` as well as `rvm docs generate-ri`. Neither have solved the issue. I am on a Mac OSx version 10.8.2.

Thanks

```
$ ri String
/Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:546:in `load': undefined class/module Encoding (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:546:in `load_cache'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:545:in `open'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:545:in `load_cache'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:384:in `initialize'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/paths.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:378:in `initialize'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:355:in `new'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:355:in `run'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/bin/ri:12
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ri:19:in `load'
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ri:19
    from /Users/zackwarburg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what you're asking so I've voted this up and not to close. Wish I had an idea what the solution is, but good luck.

Comment: Part of the problem might be that you're on a very old version of Ruby. Why not install something more recent, perhaps MRI 2.0.0p247 or MRI 1.9.3-p429?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [your version of rdoc](http://rubygems.org/gems/rdoc) (4.0.1) is very new.  As @theTinMan indicated, you may want to bump you ruby version to 1.9.x or 2.0.0 if possible.

Alternatively, you could try removing 4.0.1 and installing 3.12.2, which is the most recent 3.x variant on rubygems.

---

I dug into the source code to determine that `rdoc` is attempting to [`Marshal.load` a cache file.](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/blob/v4.0.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb#L546) Perhaps you want to clear the cache and re-run the `rvm docs generate-ri` to ensure that the cache encoding is accurate.